# SpellCheck in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, spell-checking, aspell

In FreeBSD; the SpellCheck doesn't work for me.
For example I installed `midori` from the ports. In dependencies it installed `enchant`and `enchant` had the option for some dictionary (i.e. Hspell, Aspell ...). I went with `aspell`. I even installed `aspell-en`dictionary. But at the end I have no spell check in FreeBSD.

Comment: Is it only in midori that you have no spell check, or is it in other programs too?

Comment: Jenny D in `midori` in `xchat` any place `aspell` could be used

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue on FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE, to fix it you need to install `textproc/en-aspell` or `textproc/en-hunspell` depending on the program using it.

The solution was first posted by `zeissoctopus` on FreeBSD forums: https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=41013

The`/usr/ports/UPDATING` stated an update for `aspell` port:

```
20120924:
  AFFECTS: users of textproc/aspell
  AUTHOR: bapt@FreeBSD.org

  textproc/aspell no longer installs the english dictionary. If you need it
  please install textproc/en-aspell.
```

Afterwards restart the program which needs `aspell` or `hunspell`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about FreeBSD, but I know a lot of traditional *NIX applications expect the spell checking program to be called `ispell`.  Is there an `ispell` in your path?  Linux, traditionally, made `ispell` to the relatively more modern `aspell` (the whole `ispell` interface is now considered obsolete in Linux and they have replaced it with some kind of Gnome monstrosity, but that's another story for another day).

Comment: no go on `ispell`

Comment: If you symlink ispell to aspell `ln -s $( which aspell ) /usr/bin/ispell`, aspell should work like `ispell` and be compatible with more applications.